# Is there a way to split conjunction automatically?

Tags: isabelle

I want to prove `A /\ B /\ C /\ D /\ E /\ F` in Isabelle. How can I split the subgoal to 6 separate subgoals automatically in `proof(rule ...)`, so then I can prove them separately afterwards?

Of course, I can write `proof(rule conjI)` 5 times, but maybe there is a more elegant way to do splitting in one step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `intro` method: `proof (intro conjI)`

Comment: My understanding is that `intro foo` is the same as `(rule foo)+`, i.e. it applies the rule `foo` as many times as possible.

Comment: That is not quite the case. `(rule foo)+` will only attempt to apply the rule to the first new subgoal each time, whereas `intro foo` will also apply it to all other new subgoals that arise. For instance, take `lemma "(a ∧ b) ∧ c ∧ d"` and compare `apply (rule conjI)+` and `apply (intro conjI)`. In the first case, you get the subgoals `a`, `b`, and `c ∧ d`, in the second case, you get `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to proof such goals is by using *raw proof blocks*. E.g., as follows

```
lemma "A & B & C & D & E & F"
proof -
  { have "A" ... }
  moreover
  { have "B" ... }
  moreover
  { have "C" ... }
  moreover
  { have "D" ... }
  moreover
  { have "E" ... }
  moreover
  { have "F" ... }
  ultimately
  show ?thesis by blast
qed
```

The difference is that here you do a more forward proof (which I find sometimes more readable). You just start from what you know you will have to proof at some point anyway and at the very end let some automated method (here `blast`) figure out the "trivial" steps.